# SignalR in ReactJS page works just with reload

Tags: c#, reactjs, signalr, real-time

I use signalr in React.Js and have a problem that when I go to the pages by clicking the menu link and redirect with Route, it is not working. The back-end singleton class constructor is not called, but when I refresh a page or type the route manually in the address bar, it is works and connects to the back-end.

```
    import $ from "jquery";
    window.jQuery = $;
    require("signalr");

    {componentDidMount() {
        var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:1425/");
        proxy = connection.createHubProxy("myHub");

        connection
            .start({ withCredentials: false })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Now connected, connection ID=" + connection.id);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("Could not connect");
            });

    }
```

Why does this happen and can anyone guide me on how should I fix that?

Comment: Please add minimal code

Comment: So same route typed in is fine but redirect is not?

Comment: @AvinKavish yes

Comment: Not sure if they are related, SignalR connection must be initiated by your React app no matter how you open the page.

Comment: @Justcode I added the react code